# Keep correct HTML syntax highlighting in <script> "text/html" templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, razor

Is there a way to retain HTML/ASP.net syntax highlighting and code completion within JavaScript HTML templates inside of razor views?

To help highlight (pun intended) the problem see this image of the problem:
[image]

Edit: This questions relates to Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Visual Studio, right? What version are you using?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Create a helper for it, like this, for instance: http://cangencer.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/syntax-highlighting-in-script-tag-html-templates-in-visual-studio-2010-for-mvc-3-applications/

Comment: Is there a reason this isn't in an answer instead of a comment?  This looks like a good solution to me.  Thanks!

Comment: This is the original question which prompted me to write the blog post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787376/vs2010-intellisense-inside-text-x-jquery-tmpl-script-templates/9067757#9067757

Comment: Lol, StackOverflow mutual recursion. Upvoted. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a helper for it, as shown on [Syntax highlighting for script tags with html templates in Visual Studio 2010 MVC3 applications](http://cangencer.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/syntax-highlighting-in-script-tag-html-templates-in-visual-studio-2010-for-mvc-3-applications/).

Taking the code from there, here are the essentials of what is at that link.

First, add some code to your `HtmlHelperExtensions`:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static ScriptTag BeginHtmlTemplate(this HtmlHelper helper, string id)
    {
        return new ScriptTag(helper, "text/html", id);
    }
}

public class ScriptTag : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TextWriter writer;

    private readonly TagBuilder builder;

    public ScriptTag(HtmlHelper helper, string type, string id)
    {
        this.writer = helper.ViewContext.Writer;
        this.builder = new TagBuilder("script");
        this.builder.MergeAttribute("type", type);
        this.builder.MergeAttribute("id", id);
        writer.WriteLine(this.builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        writer.WriteLine(this.builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like an `Html.BeginForm()`:

```
@using (Html.BeginHtmlTemplate("person-template"))
{
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Credits: <span></span></p>
}
```

Voila! Syntax highlighting by hiding the relevant parts from Visual Studio.

Comment: Note: if you're arriving here and wondering what went on, I posted the link as an answer originally. My answer was deleted by a moderator, who pointed me to this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259 (since my answer was just a link) and my answer was turned into a comment. By the way, if you go to that link, you get to see Jon Skeet lose a debate! :)

Comment: No problem! I'm glad you asked your question, because this was something that bugged me for a while. And I think it could be a good general solution for other cases where the syntax highlighting falls down.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in "pure HTML" files, like those I am using with Knockout :(

Comment: If it's in an ASP.NET MVC project, you can use a .cshtml to output it. Note: you can use .cshtml to output anything: HTML, CSS (can't integrate Less or Sass? Use .cshtml :)), JavaScript, etc. Give it a route and it doesn't matter that it's not "dynamic".

Answer (score 1):

It's the ["same" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14464306/1037948) for WebForms (via [here](https://cangencer.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/syntax-highlighting-in-script-tag-html-templates-in-visual-studio-2010-for-mvc-3-applications/))

*(even though the question references MVC/Razor, I got here looking for WebForms)*

### Helper

In your code-behind `.aspx.cs`

```
public string ClientTemplateBegin(string attrId, string attrType = "text/html")
{
    return string.Format(@"<script type=""{0}"" id=""{1}"">", attrType, attrId);
}

public string ClientTemplateEnd()
{
    return "</script>";
}
```

### Usage

In your `.aspx` file:

```
<%= ClientTemplateBegin("scriptId", "text/ractive") %>
    <strong>Some Editor</strong>

    {{#each items}}
        Hello {{name}}!  Your age is {{age}}.
    {{/each}}

    <pre>
    {{ json(items) }}
    </pre>
<%= ClientTemplateEnd() %>
```