# Visual Studio - Using Custom Script Tag Type for HTML Templates and Syntax Highlighting

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, angularjs

I’m using Visual Studio 2012 to edit HTML and JavaScript.  I’m adding templates by using partial views in inline script tags (see code below).  AngularJS, a Javascript framework, requires that the type be `text/ng-template`, but Visual Studio does not recognize it as being HTML and does not provide syntax highlighting. If the type is `text/HTML` everything works fine.

My question: is there a way in Visual Studio 2012 to associate a custom script type to do HTML syntax highlighting?  The solution should work not just for `text/ng-template`, but for other types where you want HTML syntax highlighting.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="filterOrder.html">
    <!-- Sidebar comment-->
    Search: <input ng-model="query"/> 
    Sort by: 
    <select ng-model="orderProp">
        <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
        <option value="age">Newest</option>
    </select>
    <div id="status">Current filter: {{query}}</div>
</script>
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/refactorthis/angularjs-visualstudio) _might_ help, though I'm not sure.

Comment: It's for this very reason I use templateUrl and load partials externally, each in there own html file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep correct HTML syntax highlighting in <script> "text/html" templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449312/keep-correct-html-syntax-highlighting-in-script-text-html-templates)

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't convince VS2012 to highlight the `text/ng-template` scripts, so I resorted to using `text/template` and added a bit to my startup code. This will enumerate the script tags of whatever type you want and add them to $templateCache.

```
    var app = angular.module('app', [...]);

    app.run(function ($templateCache) {
        // <script type="text/ng-template"> ... is preferred, but VS 2012 doesn't give intellisense there
        angular.element('script[type="text/template"]').each(function(idx, el) {
            $templateCache.put(el.id, el.innerHTML);
        });
    });
```

`text/template` triggers HTML intellisense in my setup.

```
<script type="text/template" id="home.html">
    <h3>HTML intellisense, code completion, and formatting!</h3>
</script>
```

Comment: Is there way to get the intellisense highlight syntax without code modifications?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

```
@using (Html.NgTemplate("Text"))
{
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">{{item.label}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" ng-model="item.value">
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Visual studio has no idea that it is a script tag and gives me full auto-complete.

Comment: Is `Html.NgTemplate` a custom helper?  a la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449312/keep-correct-html-syntax-highlighting-in-script-text-html-templates

Comment: Yes. Precisely or like the built in BeginForm

Answer (score 1):

Using Trey Mack's answer I wasn't able to get listings of css classes in class="".

However, by changing the tag type to text/html and modifying the app.run I'm getting syntax and CSS class name listings.

```
<script type="text/html" id="home.html">
    <h3>HTML intellisense, code completion, and formatting!</h3>
</script>
```

then...

```
var app = angular.module('app', [...]);

app.run(function ($templateCache) {
    // <script type="text/ng-template"> ... is preferred, but VS 2012 doesn't give intellisense there
    angular.element('script[type="text/html"]').each(function(idx, el) {
        $templateCache.put(el.id, el.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

P.S. I'm using VS 2015